# How fix NO_PUBKEY, EXPKEYSIG, signature invalid, sudo apt update, & repository not signed errors?

Tags: apt, package-management, upgrade, do-release-upgrade

Ubuntu 20.04 LTS Focal Fossa

I am way out of my depth here. The goal is to upgrade to 22.04 in place, without running an installer and losing all my customisations. After running the software updater a message appears inviting me to upgrade the distribution but does not proceed unless I upgrade all my installed packages first.

But `~$ sudo apt upgrade` throws a bunch of errors. I have carried out various remedies suggested in AskUbuntu but with mixed success.  Can anyone tell me what these `gpg` errors are and how to fix them?

```
    ~$ sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 4C6E74D6C0A35108 C793BFA2FA577F07 BF68EA4C8BDD0697 FC918B335044912E 5606C8D03F9E5FB8  
    Executing: /tmp/apt-key-gpghome.n6cG209zwC/gpg.1.sh --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 4C6E74D6C0A35108 C793BFA2FA577F07 BF68EA4C8BDD0697 FC918B335044912E 5606C8D03F9E5FB8  
    gpg: key 5606C8D03F9E5FB8: "home:hpcoder1 OBS Project <home:hpcoder1@build.opensuse.org>" 1 new signature  
    gpg: key FC918B335044912E: public key "Dropbox Automatic Signing Key <linux@dropbox.com>" imported  
    gpg: key BF68EA4C8BDD0697: public key "Launchpad PPA for bitseater" imported  
    gpg: key C793BFA2FA577F07: public key "Launchpad PPA for Alexander Larsson" imported  
    gpg: key B75442BBDE9E3B09: public key "https://packagecloud.io/AtomEditor/atom (https://packagecloud.io/docs#gpg_signing) <support@packagecloud.io>" imported  
    gpg: Total number processed: 5  
    gpg:               imported: 4  
    gpg:         new signatures: 1  
    gpg: invalid key resource URL '/tmp/apt-key-gpghome.n6cG209zwC/home:hpcoder1.asc.gpg'  
    gpg: keyblock resource '(null)': General error  
    gpg: key 7721F63BD38B4796: 2 signatures not checked due to missing keys  
    gpg: key A6A19B38D3D831EF: 2 signatures not checked due to missing keys  
    gpg: key CD55515EEBDB2B90: 1 signature not checked due to a missing key  
    gpg: key 7721F63BD38B4796: 2 signatures not checked due to missing keys  
    gpg: key 7721F63BD38B4796: 2 signatures not checked due to missing keys  
    gpg: key 5606C8D03F9E5FB8: 1 signature not checked due to a missing key  
    gpg: key 5606C8D03F9E5FB8: 1 signature not checked due to a missing key  
    gpg: key 5606C8D03F9E5FB8: 1 signature not checked due to a missing key  
    gpg: key 3B4FE6ACC0B21F32: 3 signatures not checked due to missing keys  
    gpg: key D94AA3F0EFE21092: 3 signatures not checked due to missing keys  
    gpg: key C8CAB6595FDFF622: 2 signatures not checked due to missing keys  
    gpg: key 871920D1991BC93C: 1 signature not checked due to a missing key  
    gpg: Total number processed: 39  
    gpg:       skipped new keys: 39
```

Comment: Better disable or remove all 3rd party PPAs you have before proceeding. You can re-enable or add again latter if necessary but keep in mind most or all won't be needed anymore. It's this simple.

Comment: Can you run "sudo apt upgrade > out.txt" and post the file's content on pastebin?